# How to find in bulk the source table names of a target table and their corresponding workflows

Tags: sap-data-services

We are decommissioning certain workflows, but in order to do that, we are trying to find out target table source and their related workflows.

I am using data services designer in order to check target table and their corresponding workflow one by one, by checking where it is used tab. How can I do this in bulk in one shot, suppose I have 50 tables. Can we query metadata tables?

I need in the below format:

```
Target table -> Source table population that target -> workflow name/step name
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Sandra  question is still not answered.?

Comment: Hi @arjun why.?

Comment: Hi @SandraRossi I am not sure. guess sap bods folks are not active here.